# WiX Setup Project - Stop Building after every compilation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, wix

I have a visual studio 2008 solution with multiple c# library projects, a Web Project and a Wix Setup project.  The setup project takes about 2 minutes to build.

Currently when I do a build, it will build every project, including the setup project.

I want to be able to build all projects, excluding the wix project when using the debug configuration.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click solution->Configuration Manager->Disable "Build" on your setup project